# How this Unique SQL injection works?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, injection

I found a challenge which was vulnerable to SQL injection and it was very very pretty hard to find So, How this unique SQL works?

I found this on login form where when I send `user=\&pass=||1#` as a payload I got successfully admin panel accessed.

This was the challenge. https://hack2learn.pw/mysql/login.php

Comment: WAIT` #` is an admin in MySQL? I thought it is a comment symbol. And what will be the use of 1

Comment: @RobertHarvey `||` is logical OR `1` (true, match all rows) and then `#` starts a comment to discard/ignore trailing text from the query including the close quote from the password, preventing a syntax error from the injection.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query in question probably looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$pass'
```

The `$user` and `$pass` variables are likely sanitized by either removing or escaping `"` and/or `'`. That's why a standard attack of `' or '1'='1` or similar is not working.

With your injection, you will get the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '\' AND pass = '||1#'
```

As you are escaping the `'` from the query, `user` is now compared to `' and pass =` (which will likely evaluate to `false`, as no such user exists). `#` is a comment which cuts off the rest of the query, so `||1#'` evaluates to `OR true`, which will be true. The authentication code will now likely fetch the first result of that query, or check if anything was returned, and thus authenticate you.